# Looking for a negatively connoted word meaning "female" for a translation

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am translating a volume of poems from German into English and am having trouble translating the German word "dämlich" - which means stupid but comes from "Dame" meaning woman or dame.

I need a word in English that has the same connotations - femininity and a negative put-down.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

In case anyone is wondering, it's not a sexist poem, quite the contrary. Here's where I will use the word:

> The female decides whether a male is successful in the game of procreation, whether she is going to let him have a go. Those without success have compensated this with two words, autocratically calling it _______.

Comment: Are you sure about the female connection of the word? [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A4mlich) strongly disagrees with your _Dame_ etymology... Actually, the English _dim_ seems a fitting translation, and might actually be a cognate.

Comment: yes, I'm German ;)

Comment: [**Bimbo**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bimbo) *- an attractive but unintelligent or frivolous young woman.*

Comment: hm. thank you, yes actually that is quite interesting to know. however, ... in the poem i'm translating it does have that connotation of feminity and i've often seen it used in German in the (faux) dichotomy of "herrlich"-"dämlich" ... in which the first, positive word has a male and the second, negative has a female connotation...

Comment: thank you FumbleFingers, but i need an adjective!

Comment: You should include in your question the sentence you're trying to use the word in.

Comment: If the (disgustingly sexist) folk etymology indeed underlies the poem, then you need _two_ words from the same vocabulary field, like _alpha dog_ and _bitchy_ as a functional equivalent.

Comment: thank you Laurel, yes, I'll do that from now on. First question on this site!

Comment: @user282874 Two more things: 1) Please [accept](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it helped you (instead of putting this info in the question). 2) If you want someone to be notified of your comment, prefix their username with an `@` (exception: you don't need to do this if the person you're talking to owns the post).

Comment: (1) You should include in your question the *part of speech* that you want.   “calling it _______” is best served by an adjective, but it’s not clear whether that’s what you want (since, for example, I have no idea how “with two words” fits in; i.e., it’s not clear what you want).  (2) “Ditzy” means [eccentrically silly, giddy, or inane](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditzy) or [silly or scatterbrained](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ditzy).  The dictionary definitions that I looked at didn’t explicitly link it with femininity, but it does seem to be used that way.

Comment: @NigelJ The epithet assumes femaleness is an *attribute of the dim person*, I don't agree that the dimness is *attributed* to the state of being female, otherwise all women would, apparently be 'blonde'. The root of the epithet is in the presumed tendency of a certain type of woman, not given to critical thinking, to bleach their hair. I expect you just had a blond moment when you tried to describe it. ;-)

Comment: @Spagirl I do not - fundamentally - agree that stupidity is anything to do with being either male or female. Stupidity has a very strong link to selfishness, in my own understanding and experience.

Comment: @NigelJ if you look closely at my comment you will see it was not about what I or you thought about gender or intelligence, but that fact that I thought you had misunderstood the thrust of the epithet.

Comment: @Spagirl I chose to delete my comment and make a further statement of a more fundamental nature.

Answer (score -1):

The correct term for a female dog, *"Bitch"*, is often used as a pejorative term for women. Though, I wouldn't recommend its use...

Comment: thank you SamLovesCoffee! actually "bitchy" works in this context. and yes, don't try this at home kids...

Comment: here's the part of the poem with your suggestion - i think it works, even though it changes the meaning a little.  "The female decides whether a male is successful in the game of procreation, whether she is going to let him have a go. Those without success have compensated this with two words, autocratically calling it “bitchy”"

Comment: Don’t you think the earlier part gives the whole thing away as a translation… it might be the best translation possible still, the result sounds alien.

Either way, how did “… compensated this with two words…” shrink to that single ’bitchy’, please?

I thought oerkelens’ Wiktionary doubt about Dame and dim seemed wholly sound, and wasn’t contradicted by anything else Google threw at me… particularly since several give dämlich as “dim-witted”. 

I also thought German had no room for variant spellings, and so would have no truck with an umlaut on dämlich.

Comment: How about airhead?  But what justification is there for calling her dim-witted because she turns him down?

Comment: @user282874 But you were apparently looking for a word which meant 'stupid', which *bitchy* doesn't. Does the need for it to be derogatory towards women override any other requirement?